# optimising a nested for loop

Tags: objective-c, loops

So, I have the following loop, and it's a bit of a bottle neck - is there any way I can speed this up?

```
NSArray *array = [an array of NSDictionaries];
NSArray *otherArray = [an array of NSStrings];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray new] autorelease];

for (NSDictionary *dict in array)
{
    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dict objectForKey@"name"]];
    for (NSString *n in otherArray)
    {
        if ([name hasPrefix:n])
            [newArray addObject:dict];
    }
    [name release];
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dict name]];`. Instead you can delete that line and replace the if condition with `if ([[dict name] hasPrefix:n])`.

Comment: If you actually post code that *would* compile, it makes reading much easier. We can only guess what [dict name] is about to do.

Comment: Do you mean `[dict objectForKey@"name"]` by `[dict name]`?

Comment: True.  Creating the string is redundant.  Just use [dict name] directly.  Probably a significant savings, since it avoids an object creation.

Comment: yes sorry: [dict objectForKey@"name"]

Comment: I did what dasdom suggested, and the loop was considerably faster! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `NSPredicate` and use

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
```

on your `array` and don't loop on your own. You need to profile if it is actually faster.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, and NSPredicate was no faster than my original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a predicate to filter the `array` & remove the loop entirely.

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(%@, $str, name BEGINSWITH[cd] $str).@count != 0", otherArray];
NSArray * newArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Assuming `name` is the key.

Comment: What sizes of `array` and `otherArray` are we talking about?

Comment: array can potentially store thousands of NSDictionaries, while otherArray contains ~100 NSString objects.

Answer (score 0):

About all I can see for substantial gains is that you could make up a boolean C-style array indexed by the first letter of your prefix and pre-load it with YES/NO based on whether that character is a "hit".  (Probably you'd want a 256-element array indexed by the low byte of the 2-byte character.) Inside the outer loop take the first character of name, index this array, and if it's NO then skip the rest of the outer loop body.  Only works if the prefix array is fairly small, though (so less than about half of the boolean array elements are YES).

You can probably make a small improvement by using a C-style array rather than the prefix NSArray, but at the expense of creating that C-style array up front.

There are other techniques that would involve hashing, but the setup expense and complexity is probably not worth it.